# imputing the mean for NA values in different columns

Tags: r

I started off with a data set that had 0 as null values. I have changed these 0 values to NA's however I want to impute the mean for the NA values. The following code is what I have done so far. Can this be done for the whole dataset or does each column need to be done individually?

```
rm(list=ls())
data=read.csv("Alzheimers.csv")
data1=read.csv("Alzheimers_diagnosis.csv")
summary (data)
alz = read.csv("Alzheimers.csv")
alz[alz==0]= 'NA'   #converting any zero values to NA
summary(alz)
```

The data set has 333 obervations of 131 variables and looks similar to this(this is only a snippet of data)

```
X   ACE_CD143_Angiotensin_Converti  ACTH_Adrenocorticotropic_Hormon AXL
1   2.6247890                        2.673159                       NA
2   0.5843270                        NA                             2.61179
3   NA                               4.613985                       0.59821
4   1.3450986                        0.760032                       4.53229
5   4.6150082                        NA                             NA
```

Comment: Try setting `,na.strings = 0` within `read.csv`

Comment: I want to change the NA's to the mean for each column

Comment: I doubt that converting zeroes to `NA`s makes any sense at all, but if you insist, after converting to `NA`s you could do something like `Res <- mapply(function(x, y){x[is.na(x)] <- y; x}, alz, colMeans(alz, na.rm = TRUE))` in order to update all the columns.

Comment: Error in colMeans(alz, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: thats the error message I am getting

Comment: So you need to select only the numeric variables then.

Comment: Create an index as in `indx <- sapply(alz, is.numeric)`, Then operate only on it `alz[indx] <- mapply(function(x, y){x[is.na(x)] <- y; x}, alz[indx], colMeans(alz[indx], na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using looping through the columns.

Example Data

```
dat<-data.frame(v1=c(2,1,5,6,7,NA,NA,9,8), v2=c(1,NA,3,6,7,8,8,NA,9), v3=c(0,0,NA,NA,NA,0,2,1,7))
```

Mean values that are imputed for every column

```
imp<-apply(dat, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Impute the mean values in df

```
df<-dat

for(i in 1:ncol(dat))
{df[is.na(df[,i]),i]<-imp[i]
}
```